# Having problems understanding OOP. Public members or getters and setters?

Tags: oop

i'm trying to learn OOP and i did read a lot of topics about OOP but I still don't fully grasp the concepts.

I'm asking for some clarification regarding that matter, in particular:
Is it fine to have public members in a class, or should I always use getters and setters?

Comment: Your question is too broad; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOP or Object Oriented Programing is a paradigm (method) of writting programs. Basically, it simplifies creating programs by considering everything as an object represented by classes.

The basic concepts of OOP (applies for all languages) are clear:

- **Inheritance:** **Object A** (or class) is able to inherit from another object, let's say **Object B**. That means that Object A, in this case the child, will inherit the attributes and methods of object B which is in this case the parent. This concepts means that you can re-use your code.
- **Polymorphism:** As the name indicates, it means than an object, more specifically, a method can take several forms. How? This concept goes with Inheritance. Say you have a parent class that is `Animal`that has a method called `talk()` that prints some text, and you have two child classes respectively called `dog` and `cat`. Both child classes would inherit the method `talk()` from their parent class being `Animal`. Both dogs and cats are Animals, but they do not talk the same way. To solve this, we would re-define the method `talk()`in the child classes using the concept of polymorphism without needing to changing the method's name or signature.
- **Encapsulation:** Last, understanding this concept should answer question 2 and 3. Basically, this means that each object or class will contain inside its own members (which provide data) and methods (which provide data manipulation). With this, what you are doing is binding the data with the methods in one container being the object. For example, let's take an Air Conditioner AC for short. An AC has attributes, let's say: make, model, isOn, temperature. Additionally, it encapsulates methods to manipulate the temperature: `tempDown()` and `tempUp()` to lower and raise the temperature by one degree.
  What you need to understand here that, the AC's methods to lower or raise the temperature are already built inside it. It is not us people who lower or raise the temperature, sure we do press the button but that only triggers the method that does that. The functionalities themselves are build inside the AC not outside it, that is to say that the methods that manipulate the AC should be encasulated inside the AC. The attributes on the other side are supposed to be `private` by concept. The AC's attributes, for example the temperature, belongs to the AC itself, it should not be `public`. It is bad practice to set a class' attributes as `public` because it defies the encapsulation concept. And so only the methods encapsulated with the attributes should have access to them. If you need to edit the attributes of an object from outside the class, you can create a method that does that for you. Methods are `public`.

At last, regarding the use of *getters and setters*, there are a lot of debates about the subject, some even describe them as "Evil". If you create methods just to access the class attributes, you might as well just set them as public and spare yourself the extra lines of code. Some languages even have better ways to manage members like using properties in Python. Like I said before, attributes should remain `private` and should only be edited/accessed by the object itself, not from the outside. The way to do that is via the methods that will manipulate them. For example, let's say you have a bank account that has an attribute : balance. If you were to set the attributes as `public` or have getters/setters, it means anyone can access your balance from outside the class and change it to whatever value they like. On the other side, if you had the attributes `private`, the class decides what sort of data manipulations you can have via the methods. A method that would only print the balance, or that would only add money if it is extracted from another account, you can even add an extra layer of secury via logging each action inside each method.

You can add Abstraction (basically separating the declaration and implementation of code through interfaces) and Overloading to the mix. You can read more information here :

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_object_oriented.htm

Comment: Nice job man, that cleared a lot of things. I am still a bit confused about abstraction but all good man.

Comment: Read this mate: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Try to be more specific in the future about your questions.

Comment: @AhmedAboumalek, you should improve your answer in an important misleading point, I mean if you allow me the suggestion

Comment: What would that be? @progmatico

Comment: "In my humble opinion, I believe that one should not use them if they want to truly follow OOP concepts." And then you present good reasoning for that when getters and setters are rrestricted to getting and setting.

Comment: "and should only be edited/accessed by the object itself, not from the outside. "

Comment: Sure you can add code to them to have them do extra jobs such as logging or doing checks but that is not their actual role, they are called getters and setters for a reason. Unless you mean something else.

Comment: Because that can be done exactly using access methods, setters that also do validation are perfectly fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182208/discussion-between-ahmed-aboumalek-and-progmatico).

Comment: Arguments against getteers and setters maybe because in some languages like Python you really don't need them (besides being unable to have privateness)